# How to group by each day in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Im trying to get statistics for each day with PL/SQL.

Each day have several entries, bukkets of errors :-) I want to group them by day.

What Im currently doing:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(dateTime, 'DD') DAY, TO_CHAR(dateTime, 'MM') MONTH, errormessage
FROM log
WHERE (...)
GROUP BY MONTH, DAY, errormessage
```

This results in ORA-00904: "DAY": invalid identifier (stops on the group by).

Any help? :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(dateTime, 'DD') DAY, TO_CHAR(dateTime, 'MM') MONTH, errormessage
FROM log
WHERE (...)
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(dateTime, 'DD'), TO_CHAR(dateTime, 'MM'), errormessage
```

Column aliases are no good for `GROUP BY`, you need the full expression.

Comment: Thank you! Acceptanse in 8 min :D

Comment: Glad to help, and you should also check out @Lukas Eder 's answer, in some cases his solution is better for readability.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is a scope problem. The `GROUP BY` clause is part of the statement's table expression and is thus evaluated before the `SELECT` clause, i.e. the projection. This means that your projected aliases are not available at grouping time. This is one solution

```
SELECT DAY, MONTH, errormessage
FROM (
  SELECT TO_CHAR(dateTime, 'DD') DAY, TO_CHAR(dateTime, 'MM') MONTH, errormessage
  FROM log
  WHERE (...)
)
GROUP BY MONTH, DAY, errormessage
```

this is another:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(dateTime, 'DD') DAY, TO_CHAR(dateTime, 'MM') MONTH, errormessage
FROM log
WHERE (...)
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(dateTime, 'MM'), TO_CHAR(dateTime, 'DD'), errormessage
```

#### Non-standard behaviour

Note that some databases (including MySQL, PostgreSQL, and others) do allow to reference column aliases from the projection in the `GROUP BY` clause. In stricter SQL dialects (such as Oracle) that should not be possible, though

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(dateTime, 'DD') DAY, TO_CHAR(dateTime, 'MM') MONTH, errormessage
FROM log
WHERE (...)
GROUP by TO_CHAR(dateTime, 'DD'), TO_CHAR(dateTime, 'MM'), errormessage
```

you can't use aliases in group by