# Oracle group orders by date and sum the total

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

My `Orders` table looks like:

```
order_id     (number)
order_total  (number)
created_date (timestamp)
status       (varchar2)
```

My goal is to get a set of rows where each row represents all orders on that date, so I'm trying to group the orders by date and get the sum of the `order_total`. I'm also limiting the results by only selecting orders from the last 30 days.

To clarify, for example if there were 30 orders in the last 30 days all on unique days then I would get 30 rows in the result. Another example: if there were 10 orders on 30th July, and only 1 order on 31st July then I'm aiming to get 2 rows in the result set, with `order_total` summed for all 10 orders in the first row, and the second row would of course have the `order_total` of the single order on the 31st.

My attempt so far:

```
select
  sum(order_total) total_amount,
  to_char(created_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') grouped_date
from
  orders
where
  status = 'Complete' and
  created_date >= (sysdate-30)
group by
  to_char(created_date, 'DD'), to_char(created_date, 'MM'), to_char(created_date, 'YYYY')
order by
  created_date asc
```

This gives an error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression

I have tried to use the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123202/how-to-group-by-each-day-in-pl-sql) but I don't think it quite fits for my scenario (this is where my group by expression has come from).

Comment: Why do you have `order_id` in the `select` list; what are you expecting to show there for a single row that sums up 10 orders? You either need to remove that, or replace it with an aggregate function.

Comment: Yes I agree it shouldn't be there, removed it thanks. Now the error changed to `ORA-00936: missing expression`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `order_id` should not be there, and that `created_date` has a time component (which seems likely as it's a `timestamp`), you need to truncate the date to remove the time when doing the aggregation:

```
select
  sum(order_total) as total_amount,
  to_char(trunc(created_date), 'DD/MM/YYYY') as grouped_date
from
  orders
where
  status = 'Complete' and
  created_date >= trunc(sysdate-30)
group by
  trunc(created_date)
order by
  trunc(created_date) asc
```

I've also applied `trunc` to the `where` clause, otherwise it would ignore any orders 30 days ago between midnight and whatever time you ran the query today. And I've used the trunc'd date directly in the `order by`, rather than the column alias, so that the order is right when you go across a month-end - ordering by the `DD/MM/YYYY` string value would put 01/07/2013 before 30/06/2013, for example.

Quick [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3963c/1).