# Select month & year between specific range in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in my table called Notenum, which increments by 1 with each new insertion.  It has about 2 million records for the past several years.

I want to find out how much (basically an average) the notenum column increases over a period of time.  I don't necessarily need to get an average returned from the query.  I'm fine with just getting a number and graphing it out, year by year or month by month.

Let's say I want to know how much it increase over the last 6 months, 2 years, etc...

Here is the query I tried to run, but I get the following error: ORA-00933: Sql command not properly ended.  This is PL/SQL

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(systemts, 'mm') Month, TO_CHAR(systemts, 'yyyy') YEAR, notenum
FROM nsa_fl.polnote
WHERE systemts
    BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2013', 'mm-dd-yyyy')
    AND to_date('01/01/2014', 'mm-dd-yyyy')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(systemts, 'mm') Month, TO_CHAR(systemts, 'yyyy') YEAR, notenum
```

I read through this [How to group by each day in PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123202/how-to-group-by-each-day-in-pl-sql), but I only got as far as this.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the value that you want is the difference between the minimum and maximum `notenum` in each time period:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(systemts, 'yyyy-mm') as yyyymm,
       max(notenum) - min(notenum) + 1 as notenum_range
FROM nsa_fl.polnote
WHERE systemts >= to_date('2013-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND
      systemts < to_date('2014-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(systemts, 'yyyy-mm');
```

I also made the following changes:

- I combined the year and month into a single column.
- I changed the `between` to two comparisons.  This ensures that you get no data from 2014-01-01.
- I modified the date format to be yyyy-mm-dd.  It is a good habit to use the ISO standard format (in my opinion).
- I removed the extraneous `notenum` from the `group by` clause.

Comment: Gordon, I think this is what I'm looking for but I get this error: "From keyword not where expected".

Comment: The column alias was `yyyy-mm` rather than `yyyymm`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have one doubt, will it give correct result if some notenum(s) are missing? E.g for the month of Jan 2014, max notenum is 1000 and min notenum is 900 and rows for notenum(s) 981 to 990 are deleted - in this can actully there are 90 notenums for Jan 2014 but you query will give 100 as a result. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your query.  First, you have a group by clause without an aggregate like sum() or count().  The one causing the error message is that the group by clause has aliases.

Comment: So, since I'm trying to "Count" the number of notenums for a given time, will that need to be added to the select?