# How do I group Oracle query results by an expression?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm trying to run an Oracle SELECT query where one of the GROUP BY fields is an expression:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, TO_CHAR(EVENT_DATE, 'HH:MI:SS AM') AS "EVENT_TIME", COUNT(*) as "EVENT_COUNT"
FROM events
GROUP BY CUSTOMER,EVENT_TIME;
```

But I'm getting this error message:

> ORA-00904: "EVENT_TIME": invalid identifier

If I use use the literal expression instead of the identifier:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, TO_CHAR(EVENT_DATE, 'HH:MI:SS AM') AS "EVENT_TIME", COUNT(*) as "EVENT_COUNT"
FROM events
GROUP BY CUSTOMER,TO_CHAR(EVENT_DATE, 'HH:MI:SS AM');
```

I get a different error:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Can I use an expression in a GROUP BY clause? If so, how?

Comment: That's odd, the second example should work as far as I know. You can always work around it by moving the to_char part to a derived table or cte, but I guess you're aware of that.

Comment: Btw: this looks like a duplicate and shows that your second statement should be valid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123202/how-to-group-by-each-day-in-pl-sql

Comment: In the first one, EVENT_DATE should work, rather than EVENT_TIME (i.e. the original COLUMN_NAME, not the the name given to the result column). Expressions do work in Group By in some languages, but I don't know about Oracle.

Comment: 2nd query should definitely work. But not sure if double quotes are required for alias name.

Comment: Remove the double quotes in the first query